# Connecting SQL server DB to A PHP web application using Wamp

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, sqlsrv

I have searched through many posts trying to find an answer but get nowhere. 
I am trying to establish a connection to and Sql Server DB through my PHP web application using WAMP.

What I have tried:

1. I downloaded the sql drivers for PHP 7 and 7.1 and tried them with the corresponding PHP versions
2. I made sure to restart all services after updating the php.ini file.
3. I haveinstalled the SQLSRV40.EXE and updated the php.ini with:

   - extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll
   - extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

I did not though that even though these are added in the php.ini they were not in the  php> php extentions list - not sure why

This is my code below allow with the error

```
<?php
    $serverName="DESKTOP-0KNJ0KP";
    $connectionInfo=array("Database"=>"SPMS_db",);
    $conn=sqlsrv_connect($serverName,$connectionInfo);

    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connected.<br />";
    } else {
        echo "Connection failed.<br />";
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

[image]

I have added context fro PHPinfo()

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats your phpinfo() say?

Comment: Most important thing. You need to install ODBC driver in your machine to support SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed `PDO_sqlsrv` part of PHP Driver for SQL Server, but your code uses `sqlsrv` functions. You have two options:

- install `php_sqlsrv_` extensions to make these functions work or
- rewrite your code to use `PDO` version of the driver

PHP code using PDO version of PHP Driver for SQL Server:

```
<?php
# Connection
$server = "DESKTOP-0KNJ0KP";
$database = "SPMS_db";
try {
   $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=$server;Database=$database", NULL, NULL);
   $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
   die( "Error connecting to SQL Server. ".$e->getMessage() );
}

# End
$conn = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting through `PDO` library (which is already installed in your server) is easier.

See PDO Book from PHP.NET: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php